# Creating array based on value - Angular 2

Tags: angular, find, ngfor

I've created list of devices where after user will click one of the devices then should appear another select box with variant of this devices.

HTML:

```
                <div class="device" *ngFor="let p of selectedDevice;">
                    <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="assets\repair\{{p.imgValue}}.png">
                    <p>{{p.text}}</p>
                </div>
                <select class="custom-select"  (change)="variants($event.target.value)">
                    <option class="text-center" value="1" selected>Choose device type</option>
                    <option class="text-center" value="{{p.id}}" *ngFor="let p of selectedDeviceDetails;" >{{p.type}}</option>
                </select>
                <p *ngFor="let a of selectedDeviceDetailsVariants;"> {{a.variant}}</p>
                <select class="custom-select" *ngIf="selectedDeviceDetailsVariants?.length >= 1">
                    <option class="text-center" value="1" selected>Choose device variant</option>
                    <option class="text-center" value="1" *ngFor="let a of selectedDeviceDetailsVariants;">{{a.variant}}</option>
                </select>
```

TS:

```
  public selectedDevice;
  public selectedDeviceDetails;
  public selectedDeviceDetailsVariants;

  variants(value){
    console.log(value);
    this.selectedDeviceDetailsVariants = this.TypesVariants.filter((x)=>x.idTypes === value);
    console.log(this.selectedDeviceDetailsVariants);
  }


  protected onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    this.selectedDevice = this.MyArrayType.filter((device)=>device.id === this.articleParams.ID_DevicesTypes);
    this.selectedDeviceDetails = this.Types.filter((device)=>device.idMyArrayType === this.articleParams.ID_DevicesTypes);
  }

MyArrayType = [
    {id: 1, text: 'Device',  imgValue: '1'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Different device',  imgValue: '2'},
   
];

Types = [ 
  {id: 1, idMyArrayType: 1, type: 'Device Details' },
  {id: 2, idMyArrayType: 1, type: 'Device Details' },
  {id: 3, idMyArrayType: 2, type: 'Different Device Details' },
  {id: 5, idMyArrayType: 2, type: 'Different Device Details' }
];

TypesVariants = [
  {id: 1, idTypes: 1, variant: '1GB'},
  {id: 2, idTypes: 1, variant: '2GB'},
  {id: 3, idTypes: 1, variant: '3GB'},
  {id: 4, idTypes: 2, variant: '4GB'},
  {id: 5, idTypes: 2, variant: '5GB'},
  {id: 6, idTypes: 2, variant: '6GB'},

]
```

When we substitute the value here manually it works (2 in example on second line):

```
  variants(value){
    console.log(value);
    this.selectedDeviceDetailsVariants = this.TypesVariants.filter((x)=>x.idTypes === 2);
    console.log(this.selectedDeviceDetailsVariants);
  }
```

But when I'm using $event.target.value - then it doesn't work although console.log says it is getting the correct value.

Where is the problem here?

Comment: May be the types are mismatching, Did you check it?

Comment: value is a string and idTypes a number

Comment: @famenev is correct - I've changed idTypes to a string and it's working right now. But is there any other solution here? I tried to convert value into a number but that seems doesn't work

Comment: @Forey cast the string to a number: `Number(value)`, `parseInt(value)`  or `+value`